# Modus Ponens false premises

Tags: logic, deduction, reason

I just started to get into deductive reasoning and was wondering how to prove an argument to be false.

In Modus Ponens:

```
If P then Q
P
thus, Q
```

If I had an argument like this:

```
P1) If you wear a tin foil hat, then aliens cannot read your mind.
P2) Sam wears a tinfoil hat.
C1) Therefore aliens cannot read Sam's mind.
```

Now, I know that Modus Ponens just tests the validity of an argument, but the premises here are clearly false and lets say I prove that it is false, what would I call this? "faulty logic?"

Also what would I say to this:

```
P2) If you wear a tin foil hat, then aliens cannot read your mind.
P3) Sam does not wear a tin foil hat.
C2) Therefore, aliens can read Sam's mind.
```

This would be denying the antecedent. The same applies here. What would I call this if the premises were false?

Comment: No a valid argument is not invalidated by false premises.

Comment: And argument is *valid* if the conclusion follows necessarily from the premises. It is *sound* if it is valid and the premises are true. So you would say that this argument is valid but unsound.